# Why DataGridView so strange when form width increase in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, scrollbar

My DataGridView is set as below.

```
    '
    'DataGridView1
    '
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowDrop = True
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.[False]
    Me.DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle1
    Me.DataGridView1.Anchor = CType(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
    Me.DataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.DataGridView1.GridColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight
    Me.DataGridView1.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl
    Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(527, 0)
    Me.DataGridView1.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 10, 0)
    Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
    Me.DataGridView1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No
    Me.DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 28
    Me.DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.[True]
    Me.DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(469, 500)
    Me.DataGridView1.TabIndex = 12
```

When the whole form's width increases to some point, the width of the DataGridView will not increase any more. And the scroll bar is so strange. The screenshot is:
[image]

**UPDATE**

After using the following code, scroll bar is still strange, but much better:

```
Private Sub frm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, MyBase.ResizeEnd
    DataGridView1.SuspendLayout()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ...
    DataGridView1.PerformLayout()
End Sub
```

[image]

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` ☆

Comment: @Codexer, Thanks. See my update...

Comment: Yup had this issue before♢

Comment: @Codexer, now scroll bar looks much better, but still strange.